# "Are" or "is" in this sentence?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> There are devices whose safeness **is/are** warranted by those methods.

The verb in question is attributed to "safeness". "safeness" is singular, so it requires "is". But "devices" is plural. So?

Comment: We don't actually use ***safeness*** in such contexts (it's ***safety***). But either way, since the referent is a singular noun the verb form must be ***is***. The plural verb form ***are*** has already been correctly applied to the primary subject *There **are devices...***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject is *safeness* (or, rather, *safety*, as FumbleFingers says), so the verb needs to be singular.

There are similar cases where usage doesn't always follow this logic, but in such cases the verb usually agrees with the closest noun phrase to the verb, even if that is not the logical subject. Here the logical subject **is** the closest noun phrase to the verb, so that issue will not appear, and any native speaker would say "is">